# The pattern of Mills Mess juggling and a link invariant in 3D?

Tags: general-topology, curves, geometric-topology, knot-theory, pattern-recognition

You can find the juggling pattern of the 3 balls called the [Mills Mess juggling here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWqpTUsIH_I).

And a [simplified animation is found here]

[image]

Observation and Attempt:
- Notice that for each of the three balls, each ball circulates its own "infinity $\infty$"-shape path. The animation makes the paths less clear, but the [above video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWqpTUsIH_I) demonstrates much more clearly.

Question:

- I wonder what would be the 3 closed curve patterns on the x-y plane, from the projection of the spacetime trajectory of 3 balls (3 ball dancing in the 3D space with 1D time) into the 2D plane such as the x-y plane shown on your computer screen?
- Can one identify the curves as the time-trajectory paths of 3 balls (allowing only a slightly deformation away from the x-y plane to the z-axis outside/into your screen direction) in 3D $\mathbb{R}^3$ space as some kind of a link invariant in 3D?

Apparently, the simplest candidates will be (1) a set of Hopf links or (2) the [Borromean rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borromean_rings).

- BUT, is it really possible to allow such **a link pattern from the 3 curves** as the 3 time-trajectory paths of the above juggling 3 balls?

Answer (score 1):

The Mills Mess pattern is very rich indeed. Several observations includes :

- We can see the trajectory as a snake formed by three balls (head, body, tail)
- These three balls *can have* fixed individual patterns (head makes a small $\cap$, body makes an $\infty$ and tail makes a big $\cup$
- The previous description is in the practical case, in your animation's case, the trajectory can be shown on the picture below(
  [Averaged pixel value on a cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roKLr.jpg))

What I did is coarsely track the balls and plot it in a 3D way. You have helixes, but it don't seem like baids (in your Borromean rings example).
[3D-plot of three cycles of Mills Mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjwH8.png)